# Storing a message in flash generates encoding troubles

Tags: grails

I have some encoding problems when using `flash.message = "Message"` to set an error message. When printing it out in the view later, like it was ISO8859-1 instead of UTF.

This is my code:

```
try {
            assert xml.results.result.size() == 1
        }
        catch(AssertionError e) {
            flash.message = "Fel, hittade mer än ett resultat. Detta ska inte hända, var god och radera en xxx för detta xxx"
            println "Error, found more than one result. This should not occur, please remove one of the result for this id."
            println e.getMessage()
        }
```

It's a standard grails app and all I have done is to use generate-all for a domain controller.

Comment: Solved it temporarily by using the built in message() method. It's still weird and I would be happy if someone could explain what's going on! :)

Comment: Probably the encoding of your file is wrong. Convert it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use:

```
render(view: "view", ..., encoding: "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your file (in your IDE) is encoding in the same encoding as Grails property:

```
grails.views.gsp.encoding
```

Should be UTF-8 by default.